# "a good man" or "a good fit"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the best answer?

> 1. I developed my skills _______ working as customer service.
>
> **a)** when
>   **b)** while
>   **c)** by
>
> 2. I'm a good ______ for this position
>
> **a)** man
>   **b)** fit

Can someone be a *good man* for a job position? Does it imply the man is "moral", "honest", "skillful" or even "kind"?

I think "fit" means the right size, can someone be the right size for a job? I don't understand.

Comment: To 2: the "a" in the sentence means that the answer should be a noun.

Comment: "as customer service" sounds wrong to me. It should be "in customer service". Any of the answers would work for that one, but it depends on the context for which is *best*.

Answer (score 1):

1. ... "while working in customer service", or "while working as a customer service representative". Customer service is a job function, not usually a job title, so you either worked in the function, or as a [job title].
2. Either "fit" or "man" works, but in modern American business communication, it's better to use gender-free language where possible, even when describing yourself. The reason is that some would consider the phrase "good man for this position" to imply that a woman couldn't do the job equally well. Not everyone cares, but it's always best to avoid accidentally offending those that do.

The phrase "to be a good fit for" is equivalent to "to fit well in", and it is a good fit for this situation.